# Is the length in mmap a number of bytes or a number of pages?

Tags: c++, c, linux, mmap

In the function:

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
```

Does the argument `length` in `mmap` represent a number of bytes or a number of pages? Also, can I use `mmap` similarly to `malloc`? What are the differences?

Comment: The `malloc` function might even be implemented *using* `mmap`. The `malloc` function is standard C (and C++), and as such is portable. The `mmap` function is POSIX, which means it will not exists on non-POSIX systems, like for example Windows.

Comment: @bolov: The manual doesn't actually answer this question explicitly.  It just says "The length argument specifies the length of the mapping".

Comment: Nate, @bolov has the reason: Some paragraphs later it says "The contents of a file mapping (...) are initialized using length bytes starting at offset offset in the file". I was a bit lazy I guess. I don't know if I should delete the question.

Comment: If you found documentation that didn't make this clear, leave the question because someone else may also be confused by it in the future.

Comment: "...are initialized using length bytes ..." farther down the man page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `length` parameter is in bytes.  The Linux man page does not say this explicitly, but the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) says (emphasis mine):

> The mmap() function shall establish a mapping between the address space of the process at an address pa for len **bytes** to the memory object represented by the file descriptor fildes at offset off for len **bytes**.

It is possible to use `mmap` as a way to allocate memory (you'll want to use `MAP_ANONYMOUS` or else map the `/dev/zero` device), but it's not in general a good direct replacement for `malloc`:

- Mappings will always be made in page units (so the system will round up `length` to the next multiple of the page size), so it's very inefficient for small allocations.
- You can't pass pointers returned by `mmap` to `realloc` or `free` (use `mremap` and `munmap` instead).
- `munmap` actually returns memory to the system, whereas `free` may potentially keep it assigned to your process and just mark it available for use by future calls to `malloc`.  This has pros and cons.  On the one hand, if you know you will not be needing that memory in the future, it is nice to let the system have it back.  On the other hand, every mmap/munmap requires a system call, which is relatively slow, whereas `malloc` may be able to allocate previously `free`d memory that already belongs to your process without a system call.